# sorting collection of type String,integer,integer in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have data of type {String, integer, integer}

```
[PR606_3,35, 9], 
[PR606_2,32, 9], 
[PR606_1,32, 10],
[PR606_1,35, 8]
```

I need to sort it on value1 then value 2 and then value3, the result should look like

```
[PR606_1,32, 10]
[PR606_1,35, 8]
[PR606_2,32, 9]
[PR606_3,35, 9]
```

What is the best approach for this in Java?
I do not have a separate class to store this data, need to use collections in java itself

Please advice! Thanks!!

Comment: Implement `Comparable` in your type...

Comment: Use comparable http://www.javatpoint.com/Comparable-interface-in-collection-framework

Comment: I'm not sure which collection to store this data before implementing Comparable

Comment: I don't have a separate class to put this data into, i need to use some collection in java itself

Comment: @aarti Why do you "need to use some collection"? Creating a class with 3 fields is easy, and then you can make it `Comparable`. Using a collection is the wrong way to go. Remember, Java is an OO language, where the first O means Object, so create a Class so you can create Objects with your data.